# Illustrator: Exporting transparent objects to png creates graphical errors

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, blending, rasterization

I have a lot of card designs I need in png format. They use linked images with alpha transparency and knockout groups with multiply blending. When I try to export to png, it produces glaring errors.

Here is a screenshot of how it looks in Illustrator:

[image: screenshot of card design in Illustrator]

And here is the output from the "Save for Web" tool:

[image: exported png of card design showing transparency errors]

The same error is created when exporting to any raster format, and with "Save for Microsoft Office".

[HERE](https://mega.nz/#!csh23YZC!jQEP2pfdcD42GO3In929wkmJSqm7bWotfB15EoLPFiM) is the file.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, Richard. I could not replicate your issue. What is the format(extension) of the linked image? And how it is built.

Comment: Do you have something else than RGB only colors? (=CMYK, Pantone?) Are you sure you are not attempting a PNG version which hasn't alpha transparency? Tried already to rasterize your artwork in Illustrator before export attempts?

Comment: Is overprint preview on? Have to verified the white objects are **not** set to overprint?

Comment: The linked images are pngs exported from Photoshop. The problem exists in both RGB and CMYK document color mode. Rasterizing doesn't seem to help but perhaps I'm not doing it right.  It _does_ show the problem in overprint preview; I don't know how to change the overprint settings on a linked png but the settings in the "attributes" window have no effect on the vectors. 
Thanks so much. If anyone could take a look at it, I've uploaded the project here: [link](https://mega.nz/#!csh23YZC!jQEP2pfdcD42GO3In929wkmJSqm7bWotfB15EoLPFiM)

Comment: If they are PNGs they are **not** vector.

Comment: Right, the file contains both linked pngs and vector path objects. Transparency is working for neither.

Answer (score 1):

Tested your linked AI file. Legacy Illustrator gave error messages and opened something which was as messy as your rasterizing attempts. The file is based on newer goods.

After changing the file name end to PDF it was easy to try other programs. Results:

Inkscape opened it, but the result was cryptic.  Making Deep Ungroup, deleting all guide texts and drawings, releasing all clipping masks and deleteting 100 not any more needed clipping paths left understandable result. Unfortunately text fonts were replaced and the knockout-mechanism vanished. The partial hiding of the parts was recreated with boolean subtracts. Result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5em5pgfwz48i6p2/MPC_stackexchange.svg?dl=0 At least it's RGB and can be eported as PNG after changing the fonts that Inkscape couldn't extract from the file.

Affinity Photo and Affinity Designer both opened it ok except fonts were replaced. Note that part of the texts are images, there's no problem with them.

[image]

This screenshot is from A.Designer. Export as PNG gave this https://www.dropbox.com/s/6x9qrsgy6q62nl3/MPC_stackexchange.png?dl=0 Of course it's useless because I do not have the right fonts.

Try at first Photoshop and Acrobat Pro (new ones). Maybe they understand how to rasterize and export as PNG. If not, get Affinity Designer (a trial is available).

You must have acceptable fonts installed, because those embedded in your file are intentionally made unusable elsewhere than in Adobe's stuff.

Comment: I like the hidden rickroll, revealed by you not having that symbol font :)